# MySQL INNER JOIN to find the max value of group of rows

Tags: mysql, inner-join, max

I have put up a sample of what I'm trying to do here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/514d2/2

This demo finds all rows in the "bids" table that are NOT the highest bid per listing_id.  What I need to do though is find all the listings, where the $userid (in this case user 1) is the highest bidder.

Can someone help me figure this out?

For those that don't use SQLFiddle...

- Tablename: listings
- Tablename: bids

SQL:

```
SELECT listings.end_date, 
    listings.user_id, 
    listings.title, 
    listings.auc_fp, 
    listings.id, 
    listings.auc_image1 
FROM listings 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
     listing_id, 
     user_id, 
     bid maxBid 
 FROM bids 
 WHERE bid 
 NOT IN 
     (SELECT MAX(bid) 
      FROM bids) 
      GROUP BY 
         listing_id, 
         user_id) 
    bids ON 
      listings.id = bids.listing_id 
  WHERE bids.user_id=1 
  AND listings.end_date > NOW() 
  ORDER BY listings.list_ts DESC
```

This query successfully finds all the listings where the $userid has placed a bid, but is not the highest bidder.  I'd like to find all the listings where the $userid has placed a bid and IS the highest bidder.

Comment: Please include enough information in the question that we can answer without having to go to SQL Fiddle or whatever.  You also need to provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  You have 17 columns in the example `Listings` table; at least 11 of them are not material to your question.  They complicate the process of understanding what you're trying to do without actually helping the question.

Comment: I've edited the question above and I'll edit the SQLFiddle as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.  Don't you need to replace the NOT IN with just IN to get the result you're after?

Comment: Well, that's what I thought but it's not working.  I thought maybe I was missing something.  When I do that it's not returning any results at all.

Comment: The SQL is oddly laid out; there's a close parenthesis where I wouldn't expect one, so I misread the query structure.

Answer (score 2):

### Preliminary observation

The original query can be reformatted for easier readability to look like:

```
SELECT listings.end_date, 
       listings.user_id, 
       listings.title, 
       listings.auc_fp, 
       listings.id, 
       listings.auc_image1 
  FROM listings 
  JOIN (SELECT listing_id, 
               user_id, 
               bid maxBid 
          FROM bids 
         WHERE bid NOT IN (SELECT MAX(bid) FROM bids) 
         GROUP BY listing_id, user_id
       ) AS bids
    ON listings.id = bids.listing_id 
 WHERE bids.user_id = 1 
   AND listings.end_date > NOW() 
 ORDER BY listings.list_ts DESC
```

I note that the column aliassed `maxBid` is not necessarily the maximum bid for any listing.  This query is also only for listings that are still open.  I'm not convinced it produces the expected answer; the only bid excluded is the one which contains the overall highest bid for any listing whatsoever.

---

### TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design

The real problem is:

> Find all the currently open listings where the $userid (= 1) has placed a bid and *is* the highest bidder.

Time to do TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design; my brain is not working fast enough to do it all at once.

#### Maximum bid for each listing

```
SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
  FROM bids
 GROUP BY listing_id
```

#### Find the bids for a listing where the user who made the maximum bid is user 1

```
SELECT b.listing_id
  FROM bids AS b
  JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
          FROM bids
         GROUP BY listing_id
       ) AS m
    ON m.listing_id = b.listing_id AND m.maxBid = b.bid
 WHERE b.user_id = 1
```

#### Find the listings where the user who made the maximum bid is user 1

```
SELECT l.*
  FROM listings AS l
  JOIN (SELECT b.listing_id
          FROM bids AS b
          JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
                  FROM bids
                 GROUP BY listing_id
               ) AS m
            ON m.listing_id = b.listing_id AND m.maxBid = b.bid
         WHERE b.user_id = 1
       ) AS u
    ON l.id = u.listing_id
```

#### Limit the query to open listings

```
SELECT l.*
  FROM listings AS l
  JOIN (SELECT b.listing_id
          FROM bids AS b
          JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
                  FROM bids
                 GROUP BY listing_id
               ) AS m
            ON m.listing_id = b.listing_id AND m.maxBid = b.bid
         WHERE b.user_id = 1
       ) AS u
    ON l.id = u.listing_id
 WHERE l.end_date > NOW()
```

You can and should replace the `*` with the exact columns you're interested in.  If you need bid details, you can obtain those too.

---

#### Testing against Informix

There's a minor syntax change required — NOW() gets replaced by CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND — but that only affects the last query.  There was somewhat more work required on the DDL to get the syntax into a more nearly DBMS-neutral format; MySQL has some odd conventions.

Note to future readers: replace the `NOW()` or `CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND` with a value such as `2012-12-29 12:37:43` to get the same results.  The listings in the data expire from `2013-01-10 00:00:001 onwards.

Query 1:

```
SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
  FROM bids
 GROUP BY listing_id;
```

Output 1:

```
listing_id  maxbid
34          95.37
40          103.00
38          507.00
41          94.00
48          76.00
6469        22.00
6472        5.00
37          511.00
31          100.00
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT b.listing_id
  FROM bids AS b
  JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
          FROM bids
         GROUP BY listing_id
       ) AS m
    ON m.listing_id = b.listing_id AND m.maxBid = b.bid
 WHERE b.user_id = 1;
```

Output 2:

```
listing_id
34
37
48
6469
6472
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT l.end_date, l.user_id, l.title, l.id
  FROM listings AS l
  JOIN (SELECT b.listing_id
          FROM bids AS b
          JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
                  FROM bids
                 GROUP BY listing_id
               ) AS m
            ON m.listing_id = b.listing_id AND m.maxBid = b.bid
         WHERE b.user_id = 1
       ) AS u
    ON l.id = u.listing_id;
```

Output 3:
    end_date                user_id     title                   id
    2013-01-09 08:11:16     1           Christmas Tree          6469
    2013-01-11 09:17:31     3           Another test item       6472

Query 4

```
SELECT l.end_date, l.user_id, l.title, l.id
  FROM listings AS l
  JOIN (SELECT b.listing_id
          FROM bids AS b
          JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid) AS maxBid
                  FROM bids
                 GROUP BY listing_id
               ) AS m
            ON m.listing_id = b.listing_id AND m.maxBid = b.bid
         WHERE b.user_id = 1
       ) AS u
    ON l.id = u.listing_id
 WHERE l.end_date > CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND;
```

Output 4:

```
end_date                user_id     title                   id
2013-01-09 08:11:16     1           Christmas Tree          6469
2013-01-11 09:17:31     3           Another test item       6472
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need using a left join to ensure there's no better bid for each product;

```
SELECT DISTINCT listings.end_date, listings.user_id, listings.title, 
       listings.auc_fp, listings.id, listings.auc_image1
FROM listings 
JOIN bids b1 
  ON b1.listing_id=listings.id 
LEFT JOIN bids b2 
  ON b2.listing_id=listings.id AND b1.bid < b2.bid
WHERE b1.user_id = 1
  AND b2.bid IS NULL
  AND listings.end_date > NOW()
```

[An SQLfiddle based on the original to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59452/4).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I kept getting false results using INNER JOIN but I have never used LEFT JOIN before. Can you tell me how I might change this query to find all listings where a user has bid, but is NOT the high bidder?  I have a query I'm using but it is also returning false results.

Comment: @Budove Sorry, not much time to write something exceptionally elegant right now, but try [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa0cf/4). Note that the userid needs to be set twice in the query to work :)